# how can i verify all links on a page as a black-box tester

Tags: python, testing, black-box

I'm tryng to verify **if all my page links are valid**, and also something similar to me **if all the pages have a specified link** like **contact**. i use python unit testing and selenium IDE to record actions that need to be tested.
So my question is can i verify the links in a loop or i need to try  every link on my own?
i tried to do this with `__iter__` but  it didn't get any close ,there may be a reason that i'm poor at oop, but i still think that there must me another way of testing links than clicking them and recording one by one.

Comment: i need to do more than just verify the link ,rather i thought of putting all the links on a page in a list and after that use the list to verify all the elements of a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use standard shell commands for this:

- You can [use wget to detect broken
  links](http://web.archive.org/web/20100626063825/http://www.gorilla3d.com:80/v8/checking-for-borken-links.html)
- If you use wget to download the pages, you can
  then scan the resulting files with `grep --files-without-match` to find those
  that don't have a contact link.

If you're on windows, you can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or install the [win32 ports](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) of these tools.

#### EDIT: Embed Info from the `use wget to detect broken links` link above:

> When ever we release a public site its always a good idea to run a
>   spider on it, this way we can check for broken pages and bad urls.
>   WGET has a recursive download command and mixed with --spider option
>   it will just crawl the site.
>
> ```
> 1) Download WGET
>
>     Mac:
>     http://www.statusq.org/archives/2008/07/30/1954/
>     Or use macports and download wget.
>
>     Windows:
>     http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
>
>     Linux:
>     Comes built in
>     ----------------------------------------
>
> 2) In your console / terminal, run (without the $):
>
>     $ wget --spider -r -o log.txt http://yourdomain.com
>
> 3) After that just locate you "log.txt" file and at the very bottom
>  of the file will be a list of broken links, how many links there 
> are, etc.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Though the tool is in Perl, have you checked out [linklint](http://www.scroogle.org/cgi-bin/nbbw.cgi)?  It's a tool which should fit your needs exactly.  It will parse links in an HTML doc and will tell you when they are broken.

If you're trying to automate this from a Python script, you'd need to run it as a subprocess and get the results, but I think it would get you what you're looking for.

Comment: i need to do more than just verify the link ,rather i thought of putting all the links on a page in a list and after that use the list to verify all the elements of a page

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is "Testing links"?

If it means they lead to non-4xx URIs, I'm afraid You must visit them.

As for existence of given links (like "Contact"), You may look for them using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could (as yet another alternative), use BeautifulSoup to parse the links on your page and try to retrieve them via urllib2.